# Помогите, не могу сделать window loader C# XAML WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

[image: вот]

как создать window loader? Программа вообще не запускается

Comment: Комментарий под прошлым вопросом не прочитали, я указал, что надо добавить в C# код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C# код вставьте обработчик, у вас его не хватает.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...тут код будет
}
```